# Launch a form from button in Google Sheets

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Forgive me if I'm asking too much here. If it's too large a query I'll chop it into several posts. This is my first GAS project so here goes...

I want my sheet users to be able to launch a form by clicking on a button in the sheet. The form should be pre-populated with certain information from the row. There needs to be other fields in the form that the user can fill. Once the form is submitted I need all of the responses to be collected on another tab in the sheet. All of the form responses should be collected on the same tab.

I hope I've not been too vague, let me know if you need any extra info/examples.

Cheers,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any sample code of what you have written so far that isn't working?

Comment: Cheers for the reply Kmeixner. Unfortunately I'm a complete app script virgin so I've no idea where to begin. I've seen a similar posts about pre-filled forms but it doesn't fit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find an example of launching a form from within a spreadsheet in [Single Google Form for multiple Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152120/single-google-form-for-multiple-sheets/17156383#17156383). It uses a custom menu, which is MUCH more reliable than an action attached to an image.

Instructions for creating a clickable image are found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets).

Comment: Great, thanks very much for your reply, I'll have a look around these responses and come back with more specific issues as they arise.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an image to a spreadsheet, and then attach a script to the image.  Some people add an image that looks like a button.  The other option is to use a custom menu.  So, start there, and see if you can get something to work.

Comment: Great, thanks very much for your reply, I'll have a look around these responses and come back with more specific issues as they arise.